# mongoose find method nothing to return but findOne have data to return

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const deviceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    deviceId: {type: String, index: true},
    alias: String, 
    deviceType:String,
    status: Number, 
    temperature: Number,
    updateTime: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, {autoIndex: false});
deviceSchema.index({ deviceId: 1, status: -1 });

Domain.models.device.find({"deviceId":requestBody.deviceID});
use find method nothing to return

Domain.models.device.findOne({"deviceId":requestBody.deviceID});
use findOne method will return data
```

I don't know why findOne have the return data and find have nothing to return.
And I try find method in PowerShell it has return value.

Comment: Sorry. I resolve it. I made a low level mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are no matches find() returns [], while findOne() returns null.

```js
Domain.models.device.find( {"deviceId":requestBody.deviceID}, function (err, results) {
    if (err) { ... }
    if (!results.length) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry.I made a mistake.